# How to create a logical partition?

Tags: partition, gparted

While installing Linux, I created three partition, primary for efi, logical for ext4 and swap. when I enter in gparted, I saw that my ex4 is primary, a lock beside the partition. how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

- If you have a GUID partition table (gpt), there can be many primary partitions, and *only* primary partitions.
- If you have an old style MSDOS partition table (mbr), there can be maximum 4 partitions, and there is a work-around: Let one of those 4 partitions be an extended partition, and in that partition you can create many logical partitions.

---

The lock symbol in gparted means that the partition is mounted and cannot be edited by gparted. If it is a system partition (root or home) of the running operating system, you cannot unmount it.

If you boot from another system (for example a USB pendrive with a live linux system), and there is a lock in gparted, you can unmount it and after that you can edit it.

Comment: I'd say that in GPT partitioning, there can be *only* primary partitions, as MBR-like extended and logical partitions don't exist in GPT.